# String variable in query - PHP

Tags: php, sql, string

I'm trying to check usernames and passwords to login to an account. (Please ignore the security problems here because this isn't a commercial project.) My code so far is below:

```php
    $accountUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["accountusername"]);
    $accountPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["accountpassword"]);
    $sql = "SELECT FirstName FROM Teachers WHERE AccountUsername = '".$accountUsername."' and AccountPassword = '".$accountPassword."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    $count = 0;
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        foreach($result as $row){
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
    echo $count;
```

This prints 0 even though the username and password given are in the database. Also, when I replace `'".$accountUsername."'` and `'".$accountPassword."'` with strings, then it prints 1 so I know the string variable is the issue.

I was fairly certain this was the right syntax since I found this in multiple places but I'm a PHP beginner so I'm not too sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$resultTeacher` or `$result` pick one, use twice

Comment: @tim Thanks, I've updated it now. It doesn't make a difference though because I just changed it when putting it on here. In my actual code, the variable is the same everywhere

Comment: mysqli_num_rows returns the count, whats the foreach loop for? not your actual code, ok, how do we help you fix your code if you dont show your code?

Comment: @tim Great point. Didn't think about that!

Comment: "Please ignore the security problems here because this isn't a commercial project" That doesn't mean it won't be a target. Insecure home systems are where botnets come from. And it's *much* harder to add security to an existing system than it is to design it with security in mind from the beginning.

Comment: @Ray It's a project for school so won't actually be used for anything.

Answer (score -2):

I've solved it now.

I replaced:

```
$accountUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["accountusername"]);
```

with

```
$accountUsername = $_GET["accountusername"];
```

Then I replaced:

```
'".$accountUsername."'
```

with

```
".$accountUsername."
```

and for some reason that worked.

Anyway, thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: assuming that accountUsername is a string, this should definitely not work. MySQL requires the strings to be quoted.

Comment: @tim That's what I thought but for some reason it did work